# In SQL, how to calculate period between started_date and end_date?

Tags: sql

I would like to query count days between start_date and end_date with this script

```sql
SELECT 
    EXTRACT (DAY FROM (MAX(controldate) - MIN(controldate))) days
FROM 
    rpt_a1903_mon_bonus_log;
```

Do you have any better script? May you share it with me?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Why do you think can be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` in your query to fetch number of days in between the given date ranges.

Try this query,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(max(controldate), min(controldate)) AS NumberofDays FROM rpt_a1903_mon_bonus_log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

> SELECT   DATEDIFF(date1, date2) AS days FROM yourTableHere;

Use the DATEDIFF() function to retrieve the number of days between two dates in a MySQL database. This function takes two arguments:

The end date. (In your example, it’s the date2 column.)
The start date. (In your example, it’s the date1 column.)
These arguments can be date/datetime values, expressions that return date/datetime values, or columns of the datetime or date data type.

This function subtracts the start date from the end date and returns the number of days as an integer.